# Sorting jsonb in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in postgresql in which data are stored as

```
CREATE TABLE foo(response jsonb);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES
('[{"qs":"field1", "ans":"a"},{"qs":"field2", "ans":"1"}]' :: jsonb),
('[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "d"},{"qs": "field2", "ans": "4"}]' :: jsonb),
('[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "b"},{"qs": "field2", "ans": "3"}]' :: jsonb),
('[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "e"},{"qs": "field2", "ans": "2"}]' :: jsonb)
```

I need to sort key 'ans' value based on value 'field1' to generate result,

```
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "a"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "1"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "b"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "3"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "d"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "4"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "e"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "2"}]


field1 | field2
  a    |    1
  b    |    3
  d    |    4
  e    |    2
```

also sorting based on 'field2',

```
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "a"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "1"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "e"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "2"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "b"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "3"}]
[{"qs": "field1", "ans": "d"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "4"}]

field1 | field2
  a    |    1
  e    |    2
  b    |    3
  d    |    4
```

is there anyway to achieve this in postgresql???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e0cc62c1cd97f3e549a6a98a8bf4f8c)

---

I am not sure if you want:

**A)** sort the JSON objects as they are:

```
| response                                                     |
| :----------------------------------------------------------- |
| [{"qs": "field1", "ans": "a"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "1"}] |
| [{"qs": "field1", "ans": "b"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "3"}] |
| [{"qs": "field1", "ans": "d"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "4"}] |
| [{"qs": "field1", "ans": "e"}, {"qs": "field2", "ans": "2"}] |
```

Query for sorting json output:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM foo
ORDER BY response -> 0 -> 'ans'
```

Simply query the `ans` value within `ORDER BY` clause. If your want to sort by `field2`, you need to change the `0` into `1` (and maybe cast it into type `int`: `ORDER BY (response -> 1 ->> 'ans')::int`)

---

or **B)** You want to sort simply the ans values:

```
field1 | field2
:----- | -----:
a      |      1
b      |      3
d      |      4
e      |      2
```

Query for sorting `ans` values:

```
SELECT 
    response -> 0 ->> 'ans' AS field1,
    (response -> 1 ->> 'ans')::int AS field2
FROM
    foo
ORDER BY 1
```

Create the two columns from parsing the array. `field1` is the first element of the JSON array, `field2` the second one (indexes `0` and `1`). After that you can order these columns ordinarily.

Comment: can we sort 'ans' of json objects based on value of key 'qs'(eg:- 'field1' or 'field2') instead of using indexes 0 or 1 as you suggested in answer (A)

Comment: Yes this is possible but more. complicated (and less fast) because in that case you need to expand the array elements to query the qs values first...

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please include that in answer so that I can compare performance between those query, one with using indexes(0 or 1) and another with the value of key('field1' or 'field2')

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=699c3486bf81c9224d45ddc3439ef023 This is really not very performant code, but it is working without any indexes. First: Expanding array to be able to query the element values by name. After that reaggregating them using a pivot mechanism with the FILTER clause.

Comment: Will this make use of any indexes if you do an `order by`?